# Why doesn't work CriteriaBuilder like for camelcase

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, specifications

"builder"  is object which from CriteriaBuilder interface

```
   Join<SedIncomeLettersEntity, CrExternalCompanyEntity> join = root.join("crExternalCompanyEntity");

builder.like(join.get("title"), "%" + value + "%");
```

this is working but doesn't work camelcase.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC like is not case insensitive and you need to manually do something like:

```
builder.like(builder.lower(join.get("title")), "%" + value.toLowerCase() + "%");
```

Hopefully that's what you need.

Comment: modifying pattern as well as values to lower case is common pattern to implement case-insensitive match...